# Why doesn't XmlSerializer support Dictionary?

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, xmlserializer

Just curious as to why Dictionary is not supported by `XmlSerializer`?

You can get around it easily enough by using `DataContractSerializer` and writing the object to a `XmlTextWriter`, but what are the characteristics of a Dictionary that makes it difficult for a `XmlSerializer` to deal with considering it's really an array of KeyValuePairs.

In fact, you can pass an `IDictionary<TKey, TItem>` to a method expecting an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePairs<TKey, ITem>>`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Hashtables need hashcode and equality comparer providers generally. These cant be serialized easily in XML, and definitely will not be portable.

But I think you already found your answer. Just serialize the hashtable as a `List<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` and then (re)construct it into a hashtable.

Comment: Or use that code: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx

Comment: What methods/properties in Dictionary imply it must be implemented as a hash table?  Dictionary and IDictionary are collections of Key/Value pairs and are distinct from the Hashtable implementation.

From a serialization perspective our goal seems to be to take data out of volatile memory to be able to load it back in at a later time.  Reloading *any* data into a different concrete implementation of an interface is going to result in different behavior.

Comment: Serializing KeyValuePair does not work. You'll end up with an empty tag. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658916/serializing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-to-xml

Answer (score 7):

This is waaay late - but I found this question whilst looking for the answer myself, and thought I'd share my eventual answer which was to replace `XmlSerializer` with a different tool that will serialize everything:

http://www.sharpserializer.com

It worked for me straight out of the box, serializing Dictionaries, and multi-layered custom types, and even generics using interfaces as type arguments. Also has a fully permissive license.

Thank you Pawel Idzikowski!

Comment: DataContractSerializer will serialize dictionaries as well, and is now part of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ExtendedXmlSerializer](https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer). 
If you have a class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

and create instance of this class:

```
var obj = new TestClass
{
    Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {1, "First"},
        {2, "Second"},
        {3, "Other"},
    }
};
```

You can serialize this object using ExtendedXmlSerializer:

```
var serializer = new ConfigurationContainer()
    .UseOptimizedNamespaces() //If you want to have all namespaces in root element
    .Create();

var xml = serializer.Serialize(
    new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }, //If you want to formated xml
    obj);
```

Output xml will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestClass xmlns:sys="https://extendedxmlserializer.github.io/system" xmlns:exs="https://extendedxmlserializer.github.io/v2" xmlns="clr-namespace:ExtendedXmlSerializer.Samples;assembly=ExtendedXmlSerializer.Samples">
  <Dictionary>
    <sys:Item>
      <Key>1</Key>
      <Value>First</Value>
    </sys:Item>
    <sys:Item>
      <Key>2</Key>
      <Value>Second</Value>
    </sys:Item>
    <sys:Item>
      <Key>3</Key>
      <Value>Other</Value>
    </sys:Item>
  </Dictionary>
</TestClass>
```

You can install ExtendedXmlSerializer from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedXmlSerializer/) or run the following command:

```
Install-Package ExtendedXmlSerializer
```