# How to to serialize a class with a private dictionary member into a file?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to write functions that save a type, the `Dispatcher` type shown below, into a file, and then reload it later.  I wrote that following functions, but they are not working.  I get an exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Xml.dll

Elsewhere I read that maybe because the member in the class is private then I should use `BinaryFormatter`, but it did not work.

What am I doing wrong ?

(The `Dispatcher` class will be used to store messages and also will allow users to pull messages from it. so I want to backup the data in case of an error and then be able to reload it).

```
public class Dispatcher
{
    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Message>>> m_DataBase;

    private Dispatcher()
    {
        m_DataBase = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Message>>>();
    }

    public static Dispatcher LoadFromFile()
    {
        Dispatcher loadedDataBase;

        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@".\DispatcherDataBase.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dispatcher));
                loadedDataBase = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Dispatcher;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            loadedDataBase = new Dispatcher();
        }

        return loadedDataBase;
    }

    public void SaveToFile()
    {
        FileMode wantedFileModeForStream;

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(@".\DispatcherDataBase.xml"))
            {
                wantedFileModeForStream = FileMode.Truncate;
            }
            else
            {
                wantedFileModeForStream = FileMode.CreateNew;
            }

            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@".\DispatcherDataBase.xml", wantedFileModeForStream))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
                serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your getting an error (just that it isn't working isn't good enough)? Does the SaveToFile output a valid xml file?

Comment: I get an Exception.

Comment: this is the Exception I get :" Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Xml.dll "    I get this Exception also if the member is public

Comment: I think this class isn't xml serializable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization

Comment: Notably: A class must have a parameterless constructor to be serialized by XmlSerializer. Only public properties and fields can be serialized. Properties must have public accessors (get and set methods). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911514/why-doesnt-xmlserializer-support-dictionary

Comment: Is there any other way to serialize this class ?(when the member is private and its a Dictionary), I didnt find any way to do so.

Comment: You should be able to use `DataContractSerializer`.  However your question doesn't include a definition for `Message` so I can't say for sure.  Could you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: @chinakid - I think I was able to figure out your problem, but in the future, when you ask a question, please 1) Include a [mcve] (`Message` was not included).  2) Include the full `ToString()` output of any exceptions including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exceptions.  Often the inner exceptions from `XmlSerializer` will be explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `XmlSerializer` to serialize your `Dispatcher` type and are encountering three separate problems:

1. `XmlSerializer` requires your type to have a public parameterless constructor.
2. `XmlSerializer` [does not support dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2911514/3744182).
3. `XmlSerializer` will not serialize non-public members such as `m_DataBase`.

[`DataContractSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer) (as well as [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer)) do not have these limitations.  If you mark your `Dispatcher` type with [data contract attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts) you will be able to serialize it to XML using this serializer.

Thus if you modify your type as follows:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string DataContractNamespace = ""; // Or whatever
}

[DataContract(Name = "Dispatcher", Namespace = Constants.DataContractNamespace)]
public partial class Dispatcher
{
    [DataMember]
    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Message>>> m_DataBase;

    private Dispatcher()
    {
        m_DataBase = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Message>>>();
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserializedMethod(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
    {
        // Ensure m_DataBase is not null after deserialization (DataContractSerializer does not call the constructor).
        if (m_DataBase == null)
            m_DataBase = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Message>>>();
    }

    internal const string FileName = @"DispatcherDataBase.xml";

    public static Dispatcher LoadFromFile()
    {
        Dispatcher loadedDataBase;

        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dispatcher));
                loadedDataBase = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Dispatcher;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            loadedDataBase = new Dispatcher();
        }

        return loadedDataBase;
    }

    public void SaveToFile()
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create))
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true })) // Optional indentation for readability only.
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(this.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, this);
        }
    }
}

// Not shown in question, added as an example
[DataContract(Name = "Message", Namespace = Constants.DataContractNamespace)]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

You will be able to round-trip your `Dispatcher` class to XML.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5b6IrP).

Alternatively, you could use `DataContractJsonSerializer` and serialize to JSON by simply swapping serializers and eliminating the optional `XmlWriter`:

```
    public static Dispatcher LoadFromFile()
    {
        Dispatcher loadedDataBase;

        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dispatcher));
                loadedDataBase = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Dispatcher;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            loadedDataBase = new Dispatcher();
        }

        return loadedDataBase;
    }

    public void SaveToFile()
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(this.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, this);
        }
    }
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CtmNfW), which results in a fairly simple, clean-looking serialization format:

```
{"m_DataBase":[{"Key":1,"Value":[{"Key":2,"Value":[{"Key":3,"Value":{"Value":"hello"}}]}]}]}
```

[json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) could also be used to serialize this type if you are willing to use a 3rd party component.