# How to write a Dictionary (collection) object to file (VB .Net 2010)

Tags: vb.net, collections, dictionary, vb.net-2010

I am attempting to write a Dictionary Collection to a file.

The Collection is structured like so:

```
GlobalCollection    (Collection of TestCollection)
    (0)
    [KEY]
    [Value]
    - TotalGlobal_W_Count    (Integer)
    - TotalGlobal_I_Count    (Integer)
    - TotalGlobal_F_Count    (Integer)
    TestCollection    (Dictionary - Key, Value)
        (0)
        [KEY]
        [Value]
        - NumberOfTests        (Integer)
        - TestCollectionName    (String)
        - TypesOfTests        (ArrayList)
        ResultsCollection    (Dictionary - Key, Value)
            (0)
            [KEY]
            [Value]
            - TotalFcount    (Integer)
            - TotalIcount    (Integer)
            - TotalWcount    (Integer)
            - ID        (String)
            - TestFolderType(String)
            - TestPassed    (Boolean)
            - FullLog    (Array)
            ResultsCollection    (Dictionary - Key, Value)
                (0)
                [KEY]
                [Value]
                - LineNumber    (Integer)
                - MessageType    (String)
                - ResultString    (String)
```

I would like to write out all of the above variables to a text file while keeping the hierarchy formatting. (Note there can be  number of elements in each collection object)

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you looked into XML Serialization?  Check out the XmlSerializer class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialize it to Xml. [Here is a StackOverflow question that answers the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671259/how-to-xml-serialize-a-dictionary). An especially good read is the link by @John Saunders in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

faster and smaller than xml, if you don't plan to parse/... the serialized file, is to use a BinaryFormater :

```
Dim MyFormatter As New BinaryFormatter()
Dim MyFile As New FileStream("Serialized.ser", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
MyFormatter.Serialize(MyFile, TheObjectIWantToSerialize)
MyFile.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, sadly we need formatting... but great answer.

Comment: Yes, indeed, GameAlchemist, binary is very fast.  (i chose binary for a lot of work, since xml was an option and I learned that if you need speed binary is faster)