# Reading and writing nested dictionaries to and from a file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, dictionary

I am newbie to Windows phone. I was successful in writing and reading a dictionary from a file. But I had stucked out in reading a nested dictionaries from a file.

1. Main_dictionary

   1. Login(Key),dictionary(value)`
   2. Validation(Key),dictionary(Value)
2. Main_dictionary

I need to write these values under a Common dictionary to a file and also need to read from the same file. Any help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please format the file content properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) as described in [How to XML-serialize a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671259/how-to-xml-serialize-a-dictionary). It references sample code in http://huseyint.com/2007/12/xml-serializable-generic-dictionary-tipi/ (not in English but the code is helpful).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution...........

public Dictionary FileRead(string Key)
        {
            Dictionary > FileResponse = new Dictionary>();
           Dictionary ReturnDictionary = new Dictionary();
           try
           {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
               {
                   using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileReader = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(DisplayMessage.Storage_Directory,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, isolatedStorage))
                    {
                        DataContractSerializer datacontract = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary>));
                        FileResponse = (Dictionary>)datacontract.ReadObject(fileReader);
                        ReturnDictionary = FileResponse[Key];
                    }
                }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return (ReturnDictionary);
        }

```
   public void FileWrite(string Key,Dictionary<string, string> FiletoStore)
    {
       try
        {
           using (IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> StoredDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
                if (!isolatedStorage.FileExists(DisplayMessage.Storage_Directory))
               {
                   using (IsolatedStorageFileStream IsolatedfileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(DisplayMessage.Storage_Directory, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isolatedStorage))
                   {
                        DataContractSerializer datacontract = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>));
                       StoredDictionary.Add(Key, FiletoStore);
                       datacontract.WriteObject(IsolatedfileStream, StoredDictionary);
                      IsolatedfileStream.Close();
                    }
                }
               else
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream IsolatedfileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(DisplayMessage.Storage_Directory, FileMode.Open, isolatedStorage))
                    {
                        DataContractSerializer datacontract = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>));
                       StoredDictionary.Add(Key, FiletoStore);
                       datacontract.WriteObject(IsolatedfileStream, StoredDictionary);
                      IsolatedfileStream.Close();
                   }
              }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
      {
       }
    }
```