# How do I load a saved dictionary from a file?

Tags: c#, dictionary, streamwriter

I have saved a dictionary with the follows:

```
 using (var file = File.OpenWrite("dictionary.txt"))
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dictionary)
                {
                    streamwriter.WriteLine(entry.Key + entry.Value);
                }
```

How do I re-open this file and store the saved data back into a new dictionary?

**UPDATE**
Answered

Comment: Search for `serialization`...

Comment: After `sw.WriteLine(entry.Key + entry.Value);` you're not really able to decide, where key ends and value begins ...

Comment: this code doesn't work... what is the variable `sw`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need serialize it to save it, then deserialize it to load it.

Your code just writes each key-value pair to a file on a separate line. This won't work because there's no delimiter between the two. There is no way to know where the `Key` part stops and the `Value` part begins. You need a better method of serializing your dictionary.

There are many ways to do this, but just to name a few, you can use XML (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671259/how-to-xml-serialize-a-dictionary)) or JSON (see [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861138/c-sharp-json-serialization-of-dictionary-into-keyvalue-instead-of-keyk)).

Comment: I see, I think I know what to do now, Thanks!