# WCF result deserializing to default values for value types in a list of key/value pairs

Tags: wcf, serialization, silverlight-4.0, datacontract

I have a WCF service and the result is a custom TimeSeries class defined as:

```
[DataContract]
public class TimeSeries
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

My service method creates an array of these objects to return.  Debugging the service method, I can see that an array containing one of these objects is created correctly (it has a name and 37 vk pairs of data).  Using Fiddler, I can see that the object is being serialized and sent (the data is still correct in the HTTP response).  However the problem comes when on the client I check the result object and it is incorrect.  Specifically, I get a TimeSeries object with the correct name, and the correct **number** of of kv pairs, but they contain the default values for each DateTime and double (ie 01/01/0001 12:00AM & 0.0).

My client is Silverlight v4 and I am using an automagically generated service reference.  The problem appears to be related to deserialization.  Anyone have any thoughts as to why it is doing this, what I am missing, or how I can fix it?

Comment: There is a valid answer, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658916/serializing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-to-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is stated in [Serializing a list of Key/Value pairs to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658916/serializing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-to-xml):

KeyValuePair is not serializable, because it has read-only properties

So you need your own class, just like the answer on that page says.

Comment: Thanks for the extra pair of eyes.  I was initially going to use Tuple<DateTime,double>, but I switched to KeyValuePairs for the semantic difference.  Guess I'll just switch back.

Comment: Just thought I'd throw this comment on for future reference: The DataContractSerializer was properly serializing the kv pairs, but since the Key and Value properties are read only it wasn't able to deserialize them.  It appears from the linked post that the xml serializer won't even serialize them.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative rather than using your own class is to use a `Dictionary<DateTime,double>` instead which seems to serialize and deserialize fine.