# Serialize a List of Key Value Pairs to XML

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

I have a `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object))` that i need to serialize to a XML string.
Note that `Object` can be one of i. `ArrayList` 
                                 ii.`String`
I am using .net framework 4.5 .

I tried looking at examples available but am unable to implement it myself.
Can someone post some kind of simple example. I am a newbie.

```
        Dim lst As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)) = fvPairs.ToList
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(lst.GetType)
        Dim stringWriter As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
        serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, lst)
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: added code for use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing a list of Key/Value pairs to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658916/serializing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-to-xml)