# Saving an integer value after string is found in text file

Tags: c#, streamreader

I've got a program that reads .HRM files and I'm wanting it to search through the text file and retrieve the integer value after whatever it states. I have it reading the text file for other things, I just can't figure this one out. As below for example:

```
if (line.Contains("Version="))
{
    //Get the integer after 'Version='
}
```

I am not too sure how to get this integer value and store it.

The HRM file reads as below:

```
[Params]
Version=106
Monitor=34
SMode=111111100
Date=20130205
StartTime=15:46:20.0
Length=01:06:18.9
Interval=1
Upper1=0
Lower1=0
Upper2=0
Lower2=0
Upper3=180
Lower3=170
Timer1=00:00:00.0
Timer2=00:00:00.0
```

Comment: Well, I'd change it to `StartsWith` first... next, you have two steps to consider: a) getting the text after "="; b) converting a string to an integer. Which of those are you having problems with?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Simplest possible key/value pair file parsing in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/284881/1260204)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you find that the line contains `Version=`

```
var number = int.Parse(line.Split('=')[1]);
```

Comment: That would try to parse "Version" and would cause a runtime error

Comment: @Ben No, the index 1 is the second item in the split string, not the first.

Comment: @Ben he fixed that,  refresh the answer

Comment: @fubo Fixed?  This answer hasn't been edited, so it was correct to begin with.

Comment: @juarr - no when you edit your answer within ~5 minutes there is no edit log

Comment: @juharr, No he's right.  I submitted it and after seeing it post, I realized that I accidentally type 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @fubo I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
int Version = int.Parse(line.Split('=')[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var versionNumber = int.Parse(line.Replace("Version=", string.Empty));
```

Or you could do RegEx and so on.

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea for `Version=1Version=2` to parse as if it were really `Version=12`.

Comment: There isn't an overload of `string.Replace` that takes only one argument.  I think you meant `line.Replace("Version=", string.Empty)`

Comment: My bad! @Jon Skeet I don't understand what you are trying to say :/

Comment: Consider a line in the file of `Version=1Version=2`. That's not valid, right? Yet your code would parse it and set `versionNumber` to 12.

Comment: That is true, my answer is expecting that Version=1Version=2 would never happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string methods `IndexOf` and `Substring`, for example with this LINQ query:

```
IEnumerable<String> versions =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"filename.HRM") // go through all the lines
    let index = line.IndexOf("Version=") // returns -1 if the line doesn't contain "Version="
    where index >= 0 // return also those which contain it
    select line.Substring(index + "Version=".Length);    // return just the version after the '=' sign

foreach (string version in versions)
    Console.WriteLine(version);
```

If you expect only one you could also use `string version = versions.FirstOrDefault();`

If you want to convert it to `int` use `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to extract just the numbers from any string you would use this:

```
int versionNumber = int.Parse(Regex.Match(line, @"\d+").Value);
```